# How do I merge based on the next closest date?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

Say I have the following data frames:

```
name <- c("Sally", "John", "Luke", "Luke", "Mary")
state <- c("CA", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NH")
year <- c(1996, 1995, 2000, 2001, 2010)

df1 <- data.frame(name, state, year)

name <- c("Sally", "John", "Luke", "Mary")
state <- c("CA", "NY", "NY", "NH")
year_election <- c(1998, 1995, 2005, 2016)

df2 <- data.frame(name, state, year_election)
```

I want to merge by exact name and state, but I want to merge year and year_election based on the next closest year. So ideally, the data frame will look like the following:

```
name <- c("Sally", "John", "Luke", "Luke", "Mary")
state <- c("CA", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NH")
year <- c(1996, 1995, 2000, 2001, 2010)
next_year <- c(1998, 1995, 2005, 2005, 2016)

df3 <- data.frame(name, state, year, next_year)
```

I have developed the following code:

```
result <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("state", "name")) %>%
filter(year.y >= year.x) %>%
  select(-year.x) %>%
  rename(year = year.y)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
i In argument: `year.y >= year.x`.
Caused by error:
! object 'year.y' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Why not just `df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("state", "name")) %>%
  filter(year <= year_election)`? This matches `df3` I think.

Comment: I think that could output multiple matches if there are ever multiple years before `year_election` in that state/name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join_by()` with the helper `closest()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

left_join(
  df1,
  df2,
  by = join_by(name, state,
               closest(year <= year_election))
)
#>    name state year year_election
#> 1 Sally    CA 1996          1998
#> 2  John    NY 1995          1995
#> 3  Luke    NY 2000          2005
#> 4  Luke    NY 2001          2005
#> 5  Mary    NH 2010          2016
```

Or something similar to your approach (credit to [Friede](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77370528/how-do-i-merge-based-on-the-next-closest-date#comment136399174_77370528) for posting this first):

```r
left_join(
  df1,
  df2,
  by = c("state", "name")
) |> 
  filter(year <= year_election)
#>    name state year year_election
#> 1 Sally    CA 1996          1998
#> 2  John    NY 1995          1995
#> 3  Luke    NY 2000          2005
#> 4  Luke    NY 2001          2005
#> 5  Mary    NH 2010          2016
```